# Syncing permissions of drive files

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I wanted to sync metadata and shares of google drive files into a database.

The solution for syncing the metadata of drive files was pretty simple. The documentation clearly states that - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-changes

The problem arises when we have to sync permissions of files. The changes.list api response doesn't tell us about the type of change event i.e. whether a permission was added or removed etc.

The straight forward solution would be to get permissions for all the files that came in the response set of changes.list api. To get better performance we can use batching here.

Is there any better solution to sync permissions? My application is performance-sensitive. A better performing solution would be a great help for me.

Thanks.